# How to write "on form submit complete" using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a form loading inside my page and there is a button out side this form its function is to submit this form.

```
$('#MyForm').submit();
```

I want a way to write a submit complete function, means to know that the form successfully/completely submitted.

I tried the jquery form plugin, but didn't work, i think because the submit come from a button outside the form.

anyone knows any different ways?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, you can use the jquery form plugin, just use the ajaxSubmit() method.

[Documentation for the jQuery form plugin.](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#api)

```
// setup the form, and handle the success
$('#myFormId').ajaxForm({
  success: function() {
     // do what you are looking to do on 
     // success HERE
  }
});

// setup submission on some random button
$('#someButton').click(function() { 
    // submit the form from a button
    $('#myFormId').ajaxSubmit(); 
});
```